# CORS error using angular httpClient with firebase functions

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this ngrx effect in my angular app that send an http request using httpClient

```
@Injectable()
export class MyEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  sendEmail$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(sendEmail),
    concatMap(action =>
      this.httpClient.post('https://us-central1-<PROJECT_ID>.cloudfunctions.net/myApi', action.data).pipe(
        map(() => actionFinished({status: HttpActionsStatus.SUCCESS})),
        catchError(() => of(actionFinished({status: HttpActionsStatus.ERROR})))
      )
    )
  ));
}
```

When I run this with firebase emulator (`http://localhost:5001/<PROJECT_ID>/us-central1/myApi` it works just fine, but when I deploy the app and trigger the request I get this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-<PROJECT_ID>.cloudfunctions.net/myApi' from origin 'https://<PROJECT_ID>.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my functions file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const email = decodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.email);
const password = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.password);
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true, optionsSuccessStatus: 200});

admin.initializeApp();

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  secure: false,
  port: 25,
  auth: {
    user: email,
    pass: password
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

exports.myApi = functions.https.onRequest((request: any, response: any) =>
  cors(request, response, () =>
    readHTMLFile('../src/assets/html/new_message.html', (err: any, html: string) => {
      const template = handlebars.compile(html);
      const htmlToSend = template(request.body);
      const mailOptions = {
        to: email,
        from: request.body.senderEmail,
        subject: request.body.subject,
        html: htmlToSend
      };

      return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, async (error: any, {}) => {
        if (!error) {
          const responseEmailOptions = {
            to: request.body.senderEmail,
            from: email,
            subject: request.body.subject,
            html: await readFile('../src/assets/html/auto_reply.html'),
          };

          transporter.sendMail(responseEmailOptions);

          return response.status(200).send(request.body);
        }

        throw error;
      });
    })
  )
);

const readHTMLFile = (path: string, callback: any) => {
  fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err: any, html: string) => {
    if (!err) {
      return callback(null, html);
    }

    throw err;
  });
};
```

Basically what it does it to send an email and a verification email back to the sender.

I'll Appreciate your help!

Comment: You've tagged this with firebase-hosting, but there is no description of how Firebase Hosting is pat of the problem here.  Please edit to explain, or remove the tag.

Comment: The solution is simple: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, e.g., it should be set on the called API. If you just want to test in your browser, this extension may help you: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: By what I can see this header is sent with the request. I can also see that the preflight request returns with status 200 but the actual request fails with that error